# How to reset a php session to starting value at certain point?

Tags: php, session

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['enter']))
    $_SESSION['enter']=$_SESSION['enter']+1;
    else
    $_SESSION['enter']=1;

    if ($_SESSION['enter']=7) {
      unset($_SESSION['enter']);
        $_SESSION['enter']=1;  // here I want to count from beginning if there are seven enters
    }
    $enter = $_SESSION['enter'];
    $enter = sprintf("%03d", $enter);
    echo $enter; //keep always 001
    ?>
```

So, I want to count page enters from `1` to `7` and then back to `1`... and so on, but in the above case it always stays on `1`.

Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if ($_SESSION['enter']=7) {
```

You are not comparing the values, but assigning it and that always returns a `true` value, causing the code after it to run.

Just change it to:

```
if ($_SESSION['enter']===7) {
```

In this case you can also skip the `if` and do:

```
$_SESSION['enter'] = ($_SESSION['enter'] % 7) + 1;
```

in your first `if` statement. More about the [modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Comment: jeroen, could you please a bit explain your last line?

Comment: @bonaca  The modulos operator gives the remainer after a division, so `$_SESSION['enter']` increases until 7 and then automatically resets to 1 as `7 % 7 + 1` is `0 + 1` is 1. Then you can forget the check later on.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($_SESSION['enter']=7) {
```

`==`, not `=`